# Why Query takes too long to fetch data

Tags: compare

This is my query on workbench

select t1.`COL 1` from ex1 t1 left outer join ch1 t2 on t1.`COL 1`=t2.`COL 1`;

why this is taking too long to fetch data?

Comment: Are the columns you're joining on indexed?  How many records are in t1 and t2?  These factors can impact your query's performance.

Comment: I try to compare two table , they both have 123 same columns, but rows numbers are different ex1 table has 172k rows, ch1 table has 142k rows.

Comment: What data types are col 1 and col 2, are they indexed, and can they be indexed?

Comment: String (which is ID)

Comment: Additional information; col1 and col2 is string but, 123 column mix of integer and string mix

Answer (score 1):

Outer joins can be slow since all of t1s records are returned.  Since you're joining on id columns, it should be easy to index them.  Without an index, when you join t2, you are evaluating each of the 142,000 records to search for matching ids.  With an index, you are setting aside memory to "remember" the locations of each id in sequence.  It's like using a bookmark instead of flipping through each page to find the page you want.

I don't know what database management system you're using, but here's a guide on creating clustered and unclustered indices on SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql